# Custom asset metadata fields

Tags: assets, metadata

Is there anyway, or any plans to add the ability to create custom metadata fields for (Pixel & Tonic's) Assets?

I can't see any references on the docs, nor any content on the web directly relating to this.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the hook for that - here's a small extension that serves as a good example on how to achieve this - https://github.com/pixelandtonic/assets_expiry_date

In templates you can grab the data using the column name.

Comment: I'm trying to add a number of custom fields to the metadata of Assets. I tried installing this Extension, but when enabled it just stops me accessing the file metadata at all when I do a right click on the image. I'm running the latest Assets and EE version. If I do get this working, would it just be a case of duplicating this script for every field that I need to add? Many thanks Pete

Comment: Old thread but would be great if I could get this working. I too am having the issues that user3008639 is having - Im on EE2.9. I'll try sorting it out and post here for others in case anyone's interested.

Comment: From what I can tell this doesnt work with Assets 2.0 or greater...which is a shame cause everything else about assets 2.0 is far better but we cant upgrade because we need custom fields